# Last June -- php relative date

Tags: php, date

I need to address last month of June. How could I achieve this?
Let say if today is **01 September 2014**, I need to address **01 June 2014** relatively. I did try...

`$dt = new DateTime('01-09-2014', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
 $dt->modify('June last year');
 echo $dt->format('d F Y');`

But It gives me **01 June 2013** and not **01 June 2014**

Any idea please?

**EDIT >>>**

If I am in-between **{July, Aug, Sep,...Dec} 2014** === I need to address **01 June 2014**

Also if I am within **{Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May} 2015** === I need to address **01 June 2014**

***Canot use php code. Only "relative date string"***

Comment: Check this [here](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon) which is very helpful if you want to play around with dates.

Answer (score 0):

```
$dt = new DateTime ( '01-04-2014', new DateTimeZone ( 'UTC' ) );
$dt->modify ( ($dt->format ( 'm' ) < 6) ? 'June last year' : 'June this year' );
echo $dt->format ( 'd F Y' );
```

Comment: Yes, but if today is 01 January 2015 then also I need to address last June, that is 01 June 2014. Actually I need this to address "Ending month of last fiscal year."

Comment: I changed it so it gets you the last june, but I wouldn't know if and how you could do it without any php code.

Answer (score 0):

if you are need a solution only in php datetime `Relative Formats` i think this is not possible for the function logic of `Relative Formats`.

// answer before question edit

something like this`?

```
$dt = new DateTime('01-09-2014', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));

if( date('n') >= 6 )
{
  // last year june
  $dt->modify('June last year');

} else {
  // current year june
  $dt->modify('June this year');
}

echo $dt->format('d F Y');
```

Comment: this is hard logic for a function, dont think this can be solved with only a date string